# Ошибка 13 Tomcat Intellij IDEA отказано в доступе к .sh файлам

Tags: tomcat, macos

При запуске программы (Mac OS X) в IntellijIDEA компилятор выдает ошибку:
(Отказано в доступе)
P.S. В терминале так же не выходит запустить файлы с расширением .sh

> Error running Tomcat 8.5.111: Cannot run program
>       "/Users/hudger/java files /apache-tomcat-
>       8.5.11/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/Users/hudger/
>       java files /apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin"): error=13, 
>       Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Используйте команду

```
chmod a+x /path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```